# nginx rewrite not including .php files?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, rewrite

I have this set up in an nginx site config, which is working perfectly to redirect all `.html` requests through to `/index.php`. However it doesn't rewrite `test.php` to `/index.php` and instead throws a 404 error.

Can anyone shed any light please? Here is my site config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
            root /srv/www/htdocs;
            index index.php;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

            location ~* \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_param HTTPS on; # <-- add this line
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                    fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
                    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated - I'm tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 1):

`location ~* \.php$` will match any `*.php` and cause `try_files` to return it regardless of its existence (hence the 404). Consider using [rewrite](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) instead!

Answer (score 1):

When a try_files directive is put directly into a server, it is only evaluated if no location matches, so it doesn't take effect if a request already ends with .php.  The way to fix this is to add a `try_files $uri /index.php =404;` inside the php location.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Is there a way to do this at the site level rather than the server level?